# How do you set a google sheets macro with the "OnEdit" function to run only on one sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I'm currently trying to make a budget spending tracker that automatically populates a date next to each purchase I track. The setup is that on sheet 2, column c is where I add my expense, and column B is where the date should be added. The code I am currently using is pasted below.

```
`function onEdit(e) {
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var dateCell = e.range.getSheet().getRange(row, 2);
  if (!dateCell.getValue()) {
    dateCell.setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("MM/dd/YY");
  }
}`
```

This is working fine except for one thing, it is activating in every spreadsheet, not just spreadsheet 2. How can I setup my code so that it only runs when another column in spreadsheet 2 is changed?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In order for your `onEdit(e)` trigger to work **only** on `Sheet2` you should add an `if` condition where you check if the name of the sheet is the one that you want the trigger be executed on.

Assuming that the sheet name is `"Sheet2"`, you can try this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
    var sheet = e.range.getSheet();
    if (sheet.getName() === "Sheet2") {
        var row = e.range.getRow();
        var dateCell = sheet.getRange(row, 2);
        if (!dateCell.getValue()) {
            dateCell.setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("MM/dd/YY");
        }
    }
}
```

**Reference**

- [Spreadsheet Class - getName](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getname)